# Can tab-width in gitkraken be configured?

Tags: gitkraken

I have a piece of code where tabs and spaces are mixed. Gitkraken seems to put a default width of 2 spaces to the tab, while the code is formatted with 4 spaces. 
Is there a way to adjust the tab-width in the gitkraken configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 3.3.0 it is configurable in the UI:

In the `Preferences > UI Preferences` menu a field "Tab Size" where this can be configured.